# Fluctuating validation accuracy with steady accuracy increase

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I have four layers of CNN to predict Javanese script letter [data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/phiard/aksara-jawa). The training accuracy and loss monotonically increase and decrease respectively. But, my test accuracy starts to fluctuate wildly. I have tried changing the learning rate, reducing the number of layers, and introducing dropout regularization. But, it doesn't stop the fluctuations. Can anyone helps me figure out where I am going wrong?

For reference, I used Adam for my optimizer and categorical crossentropy for my loss function.

I also normalized my input like so:

```
def extract_file(path):
    data = image_dataset_from_directory(
        directory=path,
        label_mode='categorical',
        image_size=(image_height, image_width),
        batch_size=32,
        color_mode='grayscale'
    )
    return data

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1. / 255)
validation_data = extract_file(val_dir)
normalized_validation_data = validation_data.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))

train_data = extract_file(train_dir)
normalized_train_data = train_data.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
```

Model setup code:

```
   image_augmentation = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.2, fill_mode='nearest', input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomTranslation(height_factor=0.2, width_factor=0.2, fill_mode='nearest'),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(height_factor=0.2, fill_mode='nearest'),
    ])

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        image_augmentation,
        # 1st convolution
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        # The second convolution
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        # The third convolution
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        # The fourth convolution
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        # 512 neuron hidden layer
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

Below is a plot of my model from epoch 1 - 50
[image: x axis in # of Epochs]
x axis in # of Epochs